# Combine two PDFs, shrink to ~3"x4" then print back-to-back

Tags: pdf, printing, scaling

I'm going backpacking and I need to carry two separate permits, but there is no restriction on the size.  I would like to take the first page of one of the PDFs, combine it with the other one (which is only one page long) then shrink it down to somewhere around 3"x4" (doesn't have to be exact), and then print it back-to-back so it's just one page.  Bonus points if I can use Kinko's and have them laminate it.

Is this something that's possible?  Is there some special software that I need to make this happen?  Are there existing guides for this kind of thing?

I tried to make this happen but I can't figure out any one of these three things, let alone all three together!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't GIMP (GIMP looks at a PDF as though it's just a bunch of image files) or Adobe Acrobat allow you to do all of this in one hit (if I'm reading this correctly)?

http://www.gimp.org/

As for the duplex printing thing you can replicate it with a standard printer if you the way in which the printer works (do a test print to determine orientation)...

You can fiddle around with pdftk but for some reason I don't think you'll like this route...

https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/

Comment: Cool, I used GIMP to turn the PDFs into PNGs, then I used OpenOffice, inserted the images on two pages, anchored them to the page, shrunk them to a third of their horizontal and vertical dimensions, centered and middled them, and then used the printer preferences to print back-to-back.  It worked!  Thanks a bunch!